# Savon adds paragraphs to base64 string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, soap, base64, savon

since half a year now I'am trying to add a bas64 encoded pdf from my rails-app to an Order in Plentymarkets via SOAP with savon. This didn't work as freely and easy as described, so I contacted Plenty-support-team, where I've been told the error was about my Base64 string containing newlines.
So I did:

```
    file = open(@kvas.pdf_attachment.url).read
    @data = Base64.encode64(file).gsub(/\n/, '')
```

But even though I tried `strict_encode64`, `url_save_encode64`and several variations of `.gsub("this",'that')`,read tons of threads 'bout base64 encoding
I allways end up with line breaks or paragraphs in the Base64-string shown in the xml-request sent via savon.
Gedit shows the string copyed from the request equally damaged, with newlines starting with `+`(each + provoces a newline) or `/` (here its more sporadic) until I switch of the automatic linebreak.
Does Savon interpret line breaks into the base64-string? and can I switch that behaviour off?

Here my Savon call:

```
    client = Savon.client(
      :wsdl => @settings.wsdladdr,
      :soap_header =>  {
                "verifyingToken" => {
                "UserID" => @tokens.userid,
                "Token"=> @tokens.token
                }},
      :open_timeout => 20,
      :read_timeout => 20,
      :pretty_print_xml => false,
      :log => false,
      :mime_multipart => true
    )

response = client.call(:add_document, message: {:oPlentySoapRequest_AddDocument => {"DocumentList"=>{"item"=>{"OrderDocumentType"=>"RepairBill", "Document"=>{"FileData"=> "#{@data}","FileEnding"=>".pdf", "FileName"=>"66667"}, "OrderID" =>"4009", "CallItemsLimit"=>"1"}}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after half a year trying everything up and down the net, I've found an answer (one day after posting this question)
It's all easy:

```
Base64.encode64(Base64.encode64(file)).sub(/\n/, '')
```

this did the trick
now the base64 string is a one_liner
who would think of that? A double encoded base64 string???!!!
I have to say, a good documentation saves you from lots of trouble